Weinberg chapter 20.5 spectral function sum rules
I've been reading through chapter 20.5 Volume2 of Weinberg's QFT and am confused about how he manage to derive (20.5.4), which read, for $x \rightarrow 0$ with $x^2>0 $:
$$\Delta_+(x;\mu^2)\rightarrow\frac{1}{4\pi^2x^2}+\frac{\mu^2}{8\pi^2}[\ln(\frac{\gamma\mu\sqrt{x^2}}{2})-\frac{1}{2}]+O(x^2).\tag{20.5.4}$$
Would someone mind me walking through the derivation from (20.5.3)?
$$\Delta_+(x;\mu^2)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int \mathrm{d}^4p  \theta(p^0)\delta(p^2+\mu^2)e^{ipx}.\tag{20.5.3}$$

AI cannot answer 100% correctly but gave lots of hints. Finally, I have almost resolved it by myself as below:
$$\Delta_+(x;\mu^2)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int \mathrm{d}^4p  \theta(p^0)\delta(p^2+\mu^2)e^{ipx}.$$
In Weinberg QFT notation, $p^2=\mathbf{p^2}-p_0^2$. $\delta$ function has the property that,
$$\delta(f(x)) = \frac{1}{|f'(x=x_n)|}\sum_{x_n} \delta(x-x_n)$$
where $f(x_n)=0$, so,
$$\delta(p^2+\mu^2) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2}}[\delta(p_0-\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2})+\delta(p_0+\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2)}.$$
As there is $\theta(p^0)$, we only take $\delta(p_0-\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2})$.
First, integrate by $p_0$:
$$\Delta_+(x;\mu^2)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int \mathrm{d}^3p\int \mathrm{d}p_0  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2}}[\delta(p_0-\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2}]]e^{ipx} \\
=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int \mathrm{d}^3p \frac{1}{2\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2}}e^{i(\mathbf{p}\mathbf{x}-p_0x_0)}\\
=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int \frac{p^2\mathrm{d}p\sin\theta \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi}{2\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2}}e^{i(\mathbf{p}\mathbf{x}-p_0x_0)}\\
=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int \frac{p^2\mathrm{d}r\sin\theta \mathrm{d}\theta}{2\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2}}e^{i(px\cos\theta)}e^{-p_0x_0}.$$
Taking $x_0=0$,
$$=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{p^2\mathrm{d}p}{2\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2}}\int_0^{2\pi} \sin\theta \mathrm{d}\theta e^{i(px\cos \theta)}$$
Taking $\cos \theta = u$,
$$=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{p^2\mathrm{d}p}{2\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2}}\int_{-1}^{1} \mathrm{d}u e^{i(pxu)} \\  
=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{p^2\mathrm{d}p}{2\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2}}\frac{1}{ipx} [\exp(ipx)-\exp(-ipx)] \\ 
=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2x}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{p\mathrm{d}p\sin (px)}{\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2}}$$
so,
$$\Delta_+(x;\mu^2)= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{p\mathrm{d}p e^{ipx}}{2\sqrt{p^2+{\mu}^2}}.$$
Set $p=i\mu\cosh(t)$,
$$\Delta_+(x;\mu^2)= \frac{\mu}{(2\pi)^2x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cosh(t)e^{-\mu|x|\cosh(t)} \mathrm{d}t \\ = \frac{\mu}{(2\pi)^2x}K_1(\mu|x|)$$
where $K_1(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.
I dig in the character of $K_1(x)$, from wolfram.com, and its asymptotic form goes as $z \rightarrow 0$:
$$K_1(z)\propto \frac{1}{z}+\frac{z}{4}[2\gamma-1+\frac{1}{8}(2\gamma-\frac{5}{2})z^2+\dots]+\frac{z}{2}\log(\frac{z}{2})[1+\frac{z^2}{8}+\dots].$$
Using this approximation, (I confirm separately):
$$\Delta_+(x;\mu^2)= \frac{\mu}{(2\pi)^2x}K_1(\mu|x|) \\
\rightarrow\frac{\mu}{(2\pi)^2|x|}[\frac{1}{\mu|x|}+\frac{\mu|x|}{4}[2\gamma-1+\dots]+\frac{\mu|x|}{2}\log(\frac{z}{2})[1+\dots] +O(x^2)\\
\rightarrow\frac{1}{4\pi^2x^2}+\frac{\mu^2}{8\pi^2}[\ln({\frac{\mu\sqrt{|x|^2}}{2}})+\gamma-\frac{1}{2}] +O(x^2).$$
I think Eq. (20.5.4) is something wrong with regard to $\ln(\gamma)$ expression.
I need more deep understanding and capability against a lots of math fields, like Bessel function, Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$, n-dimensional solid angle and dimensional regularization.

Which AI did you ask?

I have asked chatgpt, gemini, mathgpt and perplexcity, thanks.
